# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'partials' while compiling ejs

Tags: html, ejs, pm2

I can't figure out what the problem is. I've tried commenting out different parts, even commenting out the entire thing but it keeps giving me this error. I made sure to check if my code was supplying the correct template to the render and it was.

**Facing error**

```
0|index    | SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'partials' in /home/server/assets/views/register.ejs while compiling ejs
0|index    | 
0|index    | If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
0|index    | https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
0|index    | Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
0|index    |     at new Function (<anonymous>)
0|index    |     at Template.compile (/home/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:673:12)
0|index    |     at Object.compile (/home/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:398:16)
0|index    |     at handleCache (/home/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:235:18)
0|index    |     at tryHandleCache (/home/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:274:16)
0|index    |     at exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/server/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:491:10)
0|index    |     at View.render (/home/server/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
0|index    |     at tryRender (/home/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:657:10)
0|index    |     at Function.render (/home/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:609:3)
0|index    |     at ServerResponse.render (/home/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
```

wile compiling this register.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<% include partials/head.ejs %>


<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #dbdbdb;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom right, #86fde8, #acb6e5);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #86fde8, #acb6e5);
        }

        body>.grid {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .image {
            margin-top: -100px;
        }

        .column {
            max-width: 450px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ui.form').form({
                fields: {
                    email: {
                        identifier: 'username',
                        rules: [
                            {
                                type: 'empty',
                                prompt: 'Please enter your username'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    password: {
                        identifier: 'password',
                        rules: [
                            {
                                type: 'empty',
                                prompt: 'Please enter your password'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">

        <div class="column">

            <form class="ui large form" method="POST">
                <div class="ui stacked segment">
                    <h2 class="ui image header">
                        <div class="content">
                            <img src="/logo.png" style="height: 70px;">
                        </div>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="user icon"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="lock icon"></i>
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Register</div>
                    <div class="ui error message"></div>

                </div>

            </form>
            <% include partials/footer.ejs %>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am new to the field i am just trying to install and run a github project by following its readme.md file and i am stuck on this error for a while i could not found any solutions :) thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update!
doing some searching found out that changing
lines with include function such as :

```
<% include xyz.ejs %>
```

to :

```
<%- include('xyz.ejs') %>
```

does the job Thanks :)